# Initialize ATMEGA32U4 with arduino bootloader with AVR Dragon?

Tags: arduino-ide

I built my own atmega32u4 board. I wish to use it as "arduino" so I need to upload first the arduino bootloader.

Now, to do that I need another arduino but I don't have it currently.

However I have an AVR Dragon, which was the way to program these chips years back. So: how the heck can I burn the arduino bootloader to the mega32u4 with avr dragon?

Note: I can use AVR Dragon, and it can see the mega. Just I have NO clue on where this ** arduino stores it's bootloader hex file.

Comment: You mean like [this](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/tree/master/bootloaders/caterina)?

Comment: The common simple action to find a file is to use your file manager and ask it to search. You asked your file manager to search "*.hex" in your Arduino installation path, didn't you? Why do the findings not help you?

Comment: There is not a single "hex" file in Arduino IDE's folder, hence my question..

Comment: Of course not, because there are so many different Arduinos, each one needs its specific bootloader. So you might have to look at the filename. I see "Leonardo-..." as a good hint. ;-) A research on the specific Arduino that uses an ATmega32u4 with the same clock can be expected. -- And if there is still more than one left, then you could ask with the list of candidates. Or visit the project repository to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need another Arduino if you have a programmer, but there is [some problem](https://github.com/MCUdude/MightyCore/pull/14#issuecomment-191285915) with the AVR Dargon programmer and avrdude so the Arduino boards package and the MiniCore boards package don't have it configured.

With a supported programmer you can burn the bootloader with Arduino IDE. In Tools menu you select the board most similar to your custom board, then you select in Tools menu the programmer and then you select "Burn bootloader".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/tree/master/bootloaders/caterina

The file you probably want would be `Leonardo-prod-firmware-2012-12-10.hex` in that folder.

Those files will be in your Arduino installation, in a folder called "bootloaders".

Comment: I have an "Arduino IDE" folder in Program Files (Win11). Nothing is related to "bootloader" in that folder. Where am I supposed to find it?

Comment: @Daniel IDE 2.x doesn't have it, but he didn't mention anything about ide, neither did I. We both sent url with all bootloaders for 32u4

Comment: @Daniel I mentioned the "Arduino installation" - I looked in IDE 1.8.5 on Ubuntu. I can't say where it would be, if anywhere, on your hard disk for Windows 11. However the link I gave is to that folder on Github. You can click on the appropriate link in Github to open the file (it is just text), then RH-click "Raw" and then download it.

Comment: Evidently it is a file from 2012, but it doesn't matter. Either the bootloader works or it doesn't, and this one does. ;)